# IsAssignableFrom - what is the correct sequence of the parameters? Which is first and which is second?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Every time I use `IsAssignableFrom` to see if a type implements an interface or inherits from a base type, I forget which argument goes where. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isassignablefrom) is long. I always end up writing a unit test.

Given these types:

```
public interface IVehicle {}

public class VehicleBase { }

public class Car : VehicleBase , IVehicle { }
```

Which is the correct way to see if an instance of `Car` implements the interface or inherits from the base class?

Is it this:

```
var implements = typeof(IVehicle).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Car));
var inherits = typeof(VehicleBase).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Car));
```

or the other way around?

```
var implements = typeof(Car).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IVehicle));
var inherits = typeof(Car).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(VehicleBase));
```

I try to read it as "something is assignable from something" but it doesn't help me remember. I assign things *to* things. I don't assign things *from* other things.

Comment: Think of the function as a left side assignment: variable of type {firstarg} can hold instance of {secondarg}

Comment: If this is supposed to help someone, names like `IDoesItImplementThis` are completely useless (cannot even be understood from an English perspective). Use `IVehicle`, `Car` and `SpecificCar` or something like that.

Comment: @thehennyy - that helps. I've added it to the answer.

Comment: Bizarre reaction. I ask myself this same question every time I use this, and I have to dig through questions and answers to find something concise. I decided to store my question and answer on SO. I happen to personally know how helpful it is. Apparently others disagree. Oh, well.

Comment: How can you forget ? is written in method name ..

Comment: @PeterM. - I'm not the only one confused. I don't know of any such concept as "assigning a type *from* a type." I do this for a living and that means nothing to me. Even the intellisense says that the second argument is "the type to compare with the current type." Huh? When you call a method with two arguments (of the same type), which is the "current" argument? They might as well replace the word "current" with "other."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes this way:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TheRightWay()
{
    // this is what you want to check
    var implements = typeof(IVehicle).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Car));
    var inherits = typeof(VehicleBase).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Car));

    Assert.IsTrue(implements);
    Assert.IsTrue(inherits);
}
```

If you only wanted to check inheritance, you could use `IsSubclassOf`, which is much more intuitive. But if you've got two types and you want to know if there is an inheritance *or* interface implementation - perhaps you don't care which - then this will do it.

Here's a memory aid:

```
IVehicle vehicle = new Car();
```

The `IsAssignableFrom` check has the arguments in the same order:

```
typeof(IVehicle).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Car))
```

Answer (score 0):

For now i can imagine one case when you want to use reflection and ask if type is assignable from another type.

Plugins for example;

when you want declare variable you have to define type of this variable.

```
SomeType variableName;
```

Then question .. what kind of instance you can assign to this `variableName` variable?

Answer: just instance of type what derive from `SomeType` type.

Now more real world example:

```
Color variableName;
Int32 myInt;
```

Then I have question: 
Is `variableName` assignable from `myInt` variable?

Answer is: NO

now if you use reflection.:

```
typeof(Color).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Int32))
```

result is `False` so every-time think what you can assign where. Is quite simple.

Another possible way:

```
// left side of assignment  = right side of assignment;

typeof({type of variable on the left side of assignment}).IsAssignableFrom(typeof({type of variable on the right side of assignment}))
```

And about plugins I mentioned. 
Usualy you can try find all assemblies and do loop like.:

- for each assembly get all types -> filter out all types what are not implementing specific contract (type).

So then you can have

```
When my type 't' is implementing my 'contract type / interface' i want to instantiate it

and then is question 
Is my 'contract / interface ' assignable from discovered type 't' ?

and again we have left and right side and result 

typeof(my contract interface ).IsAssignableFrom(typeof( discovered type 't'))
```

Comment: In most scenarios we don't need reflection. If we need reflection there's a good chance that we're doing it wrong and we don't need reflection. If we have two variables in a method and we know what their types are because we just declared them then we definitely don't need reflection.

Comment: but here we are talking about method `IsAssignableFrom()` what is reflection based method.